# which set of numbers is the bigger real or imaginary number?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

Which set of numbers is the bigger real or imaginary number?
My teacher asked me a question which number is a bigger real number or an imaginary number? I have tried to solve the question. But I can't find a satisfactory answer. So it would be my great pleasure if someone give me the answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If, by imaginary, you mean $i\times r$ for $r\in \mathbb R$, then the two sets are the same (with the bijection being given by $ir\mapsto r$).

Comment: They have the same cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. Indeed, obviously $b\mapsto bi$.